# Why is the modulus of the denominator taken in the answer?

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

There are three lines, $y=m_{1}x+c_{1}$,  $y=m_{2}x+c_{2}$,  $x=0$. I'll have to calculate the area of the triangle formed by these lines. I calculated the intersecting points, and then calculated the area to be $$\frac{1}2\frac{(c_{2}-c_{1})^2}{m_{1}-m_{2}}$$ But according to the book, the answer's is $$\frac{1}2\frac{(c_{2}-c_{1})^2}{|m_{1}-m_{2}|}$$ Why is the modulus of the denominator getting considered?

Also if there's any better(other) way of calculating the area, please let me know that too. Thanks : )

Comment: $(c_1-c_2)^2 $ is always positive, Now negative area can be calculated only if $m_1-m_2<0$ Therefore modulus is used to avoid negative area

Comment: @h-squared uhh! Yes! Thanks. That was right in front.